# Read txt files in google colab using google drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, txt

I would like to read txt files using google drive.

In my google drive I have a dataset into this folder
'/content/gdrive/My Drive/DATASETS/DOXES/*.txt'
the data looks like this
[image]

**1) For some reason I cannot see in the ending of names the txt, is that a problem?**

**2) I would like to read this texts in google colab, I have done the following but it;s not working**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")

# Import dataset from google drive
dataset_filepaths = glob.glob('/content/gdrive/My Drive/DATASETS/DOXES/') 

print('dataset_filepaths:', len(dataset_filepaths))
> 1
```

**Updated:** Thank you so much @Corralien for your help!
I did the following to read the files

```
for filepath in tqdm.tqdm(dataset_filepaths):
  f = open(filepath, "r")
  print(f.read())
```

Which is working well, is there any way to create a pandas with all these txt files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the wildcard to list files (and not directory):

```
# You can also use *.txt instead of *
txt_files = glob.glob('/content/gdrive/My Drive/DATASETS/DOXES/*')  # <- HERE

for filename in txt_files:
    # do stuff here
```

**Update**

> Is there any way to create a pandas with all these txt files?

```
dfs = []
for filepath in tqdm.tqdm(dataset_filepaths):
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    dfs.append(df)
out = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please see the update that I have in my post?

Comment: @JohnAngelopoulos. I updated my answer according your comment. Can you check it please? (Note: I don't know the format of your text files)